# How to give a reference an explicit lifetime in rust?

Tags: memory, rust, lifetime

I'm trying to return a `Result<(), &str>` in rust, where the &str has embedded data about any errors which have occurred. For example, say I have the following code:

```
struct Foo {
    pub mynum :i32,
}

impl Foo {
    fn do_something(&self) -> Result<(), &str> {
        if self.mynum % 12 == 0 {
            return Err(&format!("error! mynum is {}", self.mynum))
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo_instance = Foo{
        mynum: 36,
    };
    let result = foo_instance.do_something().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}",result)
}
```

If I run this in the [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3d9ce8395f2e2f527a9e16c714a457aa), I get

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
 --> src/main.rs:9:20
  |
9 |             return Err(&format!("error! mynum is {}", self.mynum))
  |                    ^^^^^-----------------------------------------^
  |                    |    |
  |                    |    temporary value created here
  |                    returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

which isn't desired.
How do I tell the Rust compiler that to create a `&str` with lifetime `'a` where `'a` is the lifetime of `self`? I don't want to use `'static` if possible, and I don't want to load  `Foo` with extra members..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245834/discussion-on-question-by-tuskiomi-how-to-give-a-reference-an-explicit-lifetime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not return a `&str` in this case because the underlying object the `&str` is referencing gets dropped when the function terminates. Essentially, you are attempting to return a reference to a temporary value which gets deleted. See this article on [differences between `String` and `&str`](https://www.ameyalokare.com/rust/2017/10/12/rust-str-vs-String.html).

`String` is probably what you want instead. This compiles:

```
fn do_something(&self) -> Result<(), String> {
    if self.mynum % 12 == 0 {
        return Err(format!("error! mynum is {}", self.mynum));
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: I cannot put a string into a `Result` because it will throw an 'unknown size at compile-time' error

Comment: That error would come from `Result<(), str>` since `str` is an unsized type. `Result<(), String>` will definitely work.

Comment: @JohnKugelman seems you're right: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1cf18412c259c88013b845132b2f6ca8